# CreateContainerConfigError - Kubernetes occasionally failing to prepare subPath for volumeMount of container

Tags: kubernetes, containers, persistent-volumes

The error:

> CreateContainerConfigError: failed to prepare subPath for volumeMount "myVolumeMount" of container "myContainer"

Relevant extract from YAML:

```
        volumeMounts:
        - name: myVolumeMount
          mountPath: /var/data/crash
          subPath: files/.cores
          readOnly: false
```

I am occasionally seeing the failure show up when deploying. The fact that it is occasional is what makes this confusing. Is this a potential bug? Using Kubernetes versions: client (0.22) and server (1.22),

Comment: Is `/var` or `/var/data` also a mount?

Comment: Nope, just a regular directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the path `/var/data/crash/files/.cores` as the subPath, you need to define the `mountPath` as `/var/data/crash/files/.cores` too. Then, define the `subPath` as just `.cores`. Thus, the final block should be like,

```
volumeMounts:
- name: myVolumeMount
  mountPath: /var/data/crash/files/.cores
  subPath: .cores
  readOnly: false
```

This is how the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath) specifies too.

Comment: I don't think that's correct. The `subPath` essentially says "when ever you try to `mountPath`, `/path/inside/container`, instead write it to `/path/inside/volume/{subPath}`". I can confirm it works this way as that's the way I have it set up and it works 98% of the time. It's just this 2% of the time where I get this `CreateContainerConfigError`.